# How to see notification history on Samsung Galaxy A24?

Tags: samsung, notifications

Often, my Samsung Galaxy A24 phone makes some sound, apparently a notification. A text flashes at the top of the screen for a second. While I rush to the phone, the text has gone away. How can I see the most recent notification, or all recent notifications?

When I swipe down from the top edge of the screen, a page with many device controls appears (probably called the notification bar). Yes, it shows many notifications, but I usually cannot find there the one of a minute ago (judging by the time stamp at the top-right of the notifications tile). Today, I see there are some notifications from a week ago.

What am I missing? Is there any other place to look for recent (or all) notifications? Is there a relevant setting?

Comment: AFAIK, on some Samsung devices, there is [a built-in notification history inside the Android Settings](https://www.androidpolice.com/check-android-notification-history-guide/#:~:text=Swipe%20up%20from%20the%20home,Select%20Notification%20history.), but it needs to be enabled first in the same setting.

Answer (score 0):

This may vary by model and make, so YMMV.

Try navigating to `Notifications & Status Bar` > `More settings`.  Towards the bottom, there should be a `Notification History`; note you will need to go into that menu and toggle the feaure on before it will start backlogging your notification entries.

Once enabled, you can create a widget on your desktop and use your preferred home screen application to call on the activity directly, creating a shortcut directly to the Notification History page.